# Store Contact Information iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, contacts, phone-number

I have an iPhone app in which I need to store approximately 400-500 names and phone numbers.  I want the user to be able to view these contacts alphabetically in a plain table view with an index.  What is the best way to go about storing the names and each of their phone numbers?

Also, I need to show only the names in the table view cells, and the name and phone number on the "contact view" when the cell is tapped. How do I tell the "contact view" to show information from the specific cell that was tapped without creating 400 different views? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the contact information is predetermined then I would just pack them in the app as a single plist and read the values of it as needed.

For the detail information just create one view and pass variables to it.

Comment: Great. So the name of the contact would be the key and the phone number the value of each key as a number? And how do I pass the information from the plist to each table view cell/contact view?

Comment: Basically the view doesn't store anything, the table view datasource does. When the cell is tapped you set up your detail view and pass the variables before prsenting it. This is a fairly large topic so I would really suggest reading Apple's tableview programming guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451